# Display a one-to-many relationship in one row

Tags: ms-access

I have a "one to many" relationship in two tables:

```
Table "products" contains: product_id, product_descr
Table "packing" contains: product_id, package_id, package_desc
```

One product has often more than one package. I want to create a query in Microsoft Access, where I get all the package options for one product in one row:

```
product_id package_id1 package_desc1 packageid2 package_desc2 packageid_n package desc_n
```

The products do have a different number of packages, it's not a fixed number.

Answer (score 1):

I could achieve your query in three steps. Assuming your table values are like the values listed below:

[image]

- Step 1: In SQL View paste this query and save it as **part1**, This is for `package_id` transpose

  ```
  TRANSFORM First([packing].package_id)
  SELECT [packing].[product_id]
  FROM packing
  GROUP BY [packing].[product_id]
  PIVOT [packing].package_id;
  ```
- Step 2: In SQL View paste this query and save it as **part2**, This is for `package_desc` transpose

  ```
  TRANSFORM First(packing.package_desc)
  SELECT packing.product_id
  FROM packing
  GROUP BY packing.product_id
  PIVOT packing.package_id;
  ```
- Step 3: Join above two queries based on `product_id` to get your result